# Handle all 404 error code to custom page in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I created a custom Controller to handle all different routes, so if I enter an invalid route I raise a `NotFoundHttpException` to my custom error 404 page in `app/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`.

It is working fine with all routes except with routes that end in `.php` where I am getting the default error page. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may actually have an error in your webserver configuration.

The webserver (eg Apache/Nginx) should rewrite everything that is not a file (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) to app.php (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]`)

If you are being shown the default 404 page, I would guess there is something wrong with the webserver config.

Could you post/describe your current webserver config (Sanitized is fine, just need to see rewrite rules)?